# LinAlgError: Singular matrix while running logit model

Tags: python, logistic-regression, statsmodels

In my dataset aps1, my target variable is class and I have 50 independent features. I'm running the following code to run the model:

```
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm
model1= sm.Logit(aps1['class'],aps1.iloc[:,1:51])
```

This works fine. Now while trying to fit the predicted values:

```
result = model1.fit()
```

I get the following error:

```
LinAlgError: Singular matrix
```

Can somebody please explain to me what can be done here? Thanks.

Edit: This is what I get:

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\discrete\discrete_model.py:1214: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp
  return 1/(1+np.exp(-X))
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\discrete\discrete_model.py:1264: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log
  return np.sum(np.log(self.cdf(q*np.dot(X,params))))
Warning: Maximum number of iterations has been exceeded.
         Current function value: inf
         Iterations: 35
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-322-923286aab244>", line 1, in <module>
    result = model1.fit()

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\discrete\discrete_model.py", line 1377, in fit
    disp=disp, callback=callback, **kwargs)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\discrete\discrete_model.py", line 204, in fit
    disp=disp, callback=callback, **kwargs)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\base\model.py", line 458, in fit
    Hinv = np.linalg.inv(-retvals['Hessian']) / nobs

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\linalg.py", line 513, in inv
    ainv = _umath_linalg.inv(a, signature=signature, extobj=extobj)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\linalg.py", line 90, in _raise_linalgerror_singular
    raise LinAlgError("Singular matrix")

LinAlgError: Singular matrix
```

Comment: Is it possible that one of your columns has a duplicate or simply a multiple present in the dataset? Can you take the determinant of your training data? What value does it give?

Comment: Hi, don't think there are duplicates. the determinant gives this error: LinAlgError: Last 2 dimensions of the array must be square

Comment: Does taking the inverse of your input matrix return an error?

Comment: hi, I get the same error: LinAlgError: Last 2 dimensions of the array must be square

Comment: Which one? `LinAlgError: Singular matrix` or `LinAlgError: Last 2 dimensions...`

Comment: Last 2 dimensions..

Comment: How many rows and columns do you have?

Comment: Hi, I have around 56k rows, and 50+1 columns including the target variable.

Comment: Its probably because your input data is very close to being a singular matrix. can you try adding some small constant to the data and run it again? 
`m = 10**-6;
training_data = aps1.iloc[:,1:51];
training_data = training_data+numpy.eye(training_data.shape[1])*m;
`

Comment: Hi getting this error:ValueError: Unable to coerce to DataFrame, shape must be (56817, 50): given (50, 50)

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Change the last line `training_data = training_data+np.ones(training_data.shape)*m
`

Comment: Also, is the data available online? I mean is it open source. If possible share the data. I can check it out faster.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165124/discussion-between-clock-slave-and-dchy).

Comment: @ClockSlave what was the conclusion?

Comment: @RylanSchaeffer, I dont remember the conclusion. The chat is not available now. As far as I remember X_tranpose*X was not invertible which was causing issues. Are you facing the same issue?